# PERMISSION_DENIED error from dialogflow.googleapis.com

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I am locally running a project that uses dialogflow.  It tries to create a session like this:

```
        try (SessionsClient sessionsClient = SessionsClient.create()) {
            // Performs the detect intent request
            DetectIntentResponse response = sessionsClient.detectIntent(session, queryInput);
```

However when it gets to the detectIntent call I get this error:

```
        PERMISSION_DENIED: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the dialogflow.googleapis.com.
```

I'm mystified by this - I'm setting the env GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS like this -

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="$HOME/project-name-623-974376412c16.json"
```

I created the service account in the service account section of the project in the gcp console.

The GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS points to a json file with service account credentials.  And the service account is set as the active account, and associated with my dialog flow project.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you provide some more information: How are you setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`? What is the SDK language? Can you print `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to show that the file path is correct? How did you create the service account?

Comment: @AndyShinn thanks, have added more details!

Comment: Can you print the content of the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env var in your code to be sure that it is set at runtime?